# Tablet says "SD Card Mounted"

Tags: external-sd, tablet

For some reason, my tablet has a notification that says there is a sd card mounted, although it doesn't even have and sd card.

Is there a reason for this, if so how do I rid myself of the notification?

Comment: No, it won't swipe and when I click on it it takes me to settings, although it isn't in a specific menu.

Comment: Try "tap-and-hold" (long press the notification). See if there's an option to "silence" it.

Comment: Okay. That seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I've never seen this kind of notification sticking (or even appearing): It's obviously informing you that your SD card was mounted. Note that almost all recent Android devices come with an [internal-sd](/questions/tagged/internal-sd) card – so even if you have no external card, there's still one that should be mounted.

The other part of your question is a general one on notifications. First, there are two kind of notifications: the best known are those just giving you a one-time information, and you can simply "swipe them out". The other kind are so-called "ongoing notifications", and they "stick" (i.e. they cannot be "swiped out"). The only way to get rid of them is "silencing" the app giving them. Long-pressing a notification gives you a menu to do exactly that: telling the system you don't want this app giving you notifications.